# Setting up a Problem for Induction that Involves Inequality and a Function

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

The problem states:

*Use mathematical induction to prove that any stack of ($n\geq 5$) pancakes can be 
sorted using at most $2n-5$ flips.  You may use the fact  any stack of $5$ pancakes can be 
sorted with at most $5$ flips*

I am trying to set it up for induction but I am having trouble doing so.

So far I have done this:

$F(n)\leq 2n-5$

Where F is the function to represent the number of flips at most to sort $n$ number of pancakes.

From there I got to the Base Case(note the problem supplied a possible base case that I am using here):

$F(5)\leq 2\cdot 5-5$

$5\leq 5$ is True.

Using this base case say that $n=5$ is represented as $k$. I need to prove that $k+1$ will also be valid. This is where I get stuck and I wonder if its an issue with how I tried to capture the question mathematically. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to better approach it. I'm very new to all this.

*Scratch Work that leads to my stump*:

$$F(k + 1) \leq 2(k + 1) -5$$

$$F(k + 1) \leq 2k -3$$

Not sure how to work with this in a way that would tell me anything useful. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is using the concept of Pancake Sorting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F(n)$ denotes the number of flips required to sort $n$
pancakes then you want to show that the statement
$$ 
 S(n): F(n) \le 2n - 5 
$$ 
is true for $n \ge 5$.

The base case is $S(5): F(5) \le 2\cdot 5 - 5 = 5$ and that is given.

Now you have to show that for all $n \ge 5$: $S(n) \Longrightarrow S(n+1)$, in other words,
$$
  F(n) \le 2n-5 \Longrightarrow F(n+1) \le 2(n+1) - 5
$$
and that follows from the observation (taken from https://oeis.org/A058986):

> If the worst case for n pancakes is x flips, then the worst case for n
>   + 1 pancakes can be no greater than x + 2 flips. Getting the n + 1 pancake to the bottom of the pile will require 0, 1 or 2 flips, after
>   which you can sort the n remaining pancakes in at most x flips.

which implies that $F(n+1) \le F(n) + 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Still a little confused. This needs to be shown correct: S(n)⟹S(n+1). However, I'm not sure how the observation you pointed out from the outside source supports that  F(n)≤2n−5 does in fact imply that F(n+1)≤2(n+1)−5.

Comment: @StevenOL: The observation is that $F(n+1) \le F(n) + 2$. Therefore $F(n) \le 2n-5$ implies that $F(n+1) \le F(n) + 2 \le (2n-5) + 2 = 2(n+1) -5$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @StevenOL: You are welcome!